# Just deployed an EAR with a War file to Jboss 6.1 deployments directory. What is the default http port number?

Tags: java, jboss, java-ee-6, jboss6.x, appserver

My EAR has two WARs and a bunch of jars. It looks to have deployed successfully from the logs and shows up in the JBoss admin console at `localhost:9990/console`. Though I specified port 80 as my http socket-binding in standalone.xml:

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="80"/>
```

This allows me to login to the admin console at `localhost:80` but I do not see either web app at `localhost:80/<context-root value>`

What port are my webapps being served from by JBoss?

Comment: after deploying your war have you look at the log while starting server do you find any error?

Comment: " It looks to have deployed successfully from the logs "

Comment: use localhost:8080/ that will work

Comment: no it won't - I already said I changed the port to 80 in my question

Comment: May be your Jboss not up properly Or any other process already used port 80

Comment: As I said in the question, JBoss is listening on port 80. An error would show in the logs on startup otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the http binding port from 8080 to 80 in jboss/server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml?

```
        <bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
           <property name="serviceName">jboss.web:service=WebServer</property>
           <property name="bindingName">HttpConnector</property>
           <property name="port">8080</property>
           <property name="description">JBoss Web HTTP connector socket; also drives the values for the HTTPS and AJP sockets</property>
        </bean>
```